# Manhua about an alchemist/refiner who was reincarnated into a trash guy

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a colored manhua where this guy was really strong. He was an alchemist/refiner and a martial artist but got into conflict died and reincarnated into trash guy in a small country.

Now skip forward and his family (LI family I belive) had internal issues and he went home. The butler who was in control was a spy. He defeats him and found his grand father that was supposed to be sick or something and an old guy who were a general of the country with his grand father and cured him.

This is all I remembered.

Comment: Just to be clear, is he a "trash guy" in that he lacks power? Or is he a sanitation worker who picks up trash? Are the alchemist and the "trash guy" on Earth? Present day? Victorian era? Qin dynasty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ***[The Supreme Way](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/99rau33/divine-path-to-supremacy)***.

> This is a world where everyone can become a god. Those who select the Divine Path of Thunder will become the Gods of Thunder. Those who choose the Divine Path of Mountains will become the Gods of Mountains. Once mortals become gods, they can create their own divine realms. Li Cang, a time traveler, didn't have money or talents. He thought he couldn't become a cultivator, but accidentally, he became the first person who created a divine realm before he became a god!

I just came across it recently. He had the divine realm ahead of when he should and it helped him with his cultivation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back and updating this.  Can you improve your answer by adding a link and/or a summary?

Comment: No problem thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2):

Might it be *[I am Trash](https://www.bilibilicomics.com/detail/mc1807)*, aka *I'm a Loser, Baby*?

[image: Front cover of I am Trash]

> I'm a Loser, Baby: Being looked down on, divorced, and killed—maybe that’s the life of a loser after all... However, I was reborn by Cang Kunzi, the best cultivator in the world of immortal cultivation. If that’s the case, I may as well make the best out of this situation. Watch how I use this body of a loser to crush all of you powerless bunch!

Comment: Wasn't this but this looks interesting thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the points that don't match? That's sometimes a good way to elicit more details for your question.

Comment: Everything occurred in the cultivation world for this one the cultivator came over to earth but that one the cultivator went into the body of a person in that same world

Answer (score 2):

***[The Ultimate of All Ages](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/l4ho1jh/rebirth-of-the-ultimate-master)*** is the name you are looking for.

> What happens when a former martial emperor gets reborn into a complete loser's body? Scott Dillon, a legendary martial artist who was ranked third-strongest in the continent, finds himself in this predicament when he wakes up in the body of 15-year-old Kerwin Walton. Kerwin was once a failure who had yet to open a single chakra portal in his body, but now he's morphed into a genius martial artist overnight and becomes the talk (and target) of the town. Armed with the expertise of his former life, Kerwin is on a mission to complete the ultimate incantation that killed him in the first place - all while wiping the floor with his former bullies at school. Will Kerwin be able to exceed the accomplishments of his previous life? One thing's for certain: no one will ever call Kerwin a loser again!

Comment: Note that the OP [answered their own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/270705/122024), clarifying that the manhua they were looking for is _The Supreme Way_.

Comment: @LogicDictates - although it is a decent suggested answer in its own right and might help someone looking for something similar...