# Manga/manhua where an uncle kills his nephew. A martial artist takes over the nephew's body and memories

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is on the balcony with his uncle. The uncle decides to push his nephew off the balcony. The main character then ends up in the hospital, where a martial artist takes over/reincarnated into his body.

When the martial artist/cultivator takes over the nephew has passed on and he inherits that person’s memories

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Also, when the martial artist takes over, does the nephew cease to be?

Comment: I read this about a year ago. When the martial artist/cultivator takes over the the nephew has passed on and he inherits that person’s memories

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the main character's name? What was his uncle's name? Why did he attempt to murder his nephew? What was the setting for the story? Was it in colour or black-and-white? Was it explicit (with gore and/or nudity) or something tamer? After the main character has a spirit enter him, does he continue to exist or is he effectively dead?

Comment: I do not remember the characters names. It is in black-and-white. The body that the martial artist/cultivator and up and having ends up passing away which allows for the martial artist/cultivator to take over, but he does end up, inheriting the previous owners memories. The reason why the uncle did it was to get his nephews inheritance.

Comment: I think I recall this one... the nephew keeps being referred to as "trash", but people think a demon took him over?

Comment: I do remember that it takes place on earth modern times when the martial artist/cultivator takes over the nephews body.

Comment: I did find a link using Google which led to a Reddit site, but when I clicked on the link, it wasn’t there anymore it seems. so a friend of mine referred me to this website because he said that he found it very helpful to him.

Comment: @CodyMeeks: Yeah, Reddit's currently doing a strike thing in a number of communities due to upcoming changes in the API that are going to hamstring some communities. This is immensely frustrating because I know I read this about 2 years ago (assuming it's the same one), but I don't have any bookmarks. Another salient bit I remember is that he picks up electricity powers, which he uses to subtly disable some of the mooks working for his uncle.

Comment: I found it. You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons ad per the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[The Loser's Counterattack](https://m.webcomicsapp.com/comic/The-Loser-s-Counterattack/6369fd048c252b181b1dc1da)* aka *I Was Trash*

[image: Front cover of I Was Trash]

> They say that being a loser is about being despised by others, rejected from marriage, and eventually tortured to death. This was exactly what happened to Lin Mu – a loser who was murdered by someone he called uncle. However, things take a turn for the better when a matchless cultivator from the Cultivation Realm possesses Lin Mu's body...
> They say that being a loser is about being despised by others, rejected from marriage, and eventually tortured to death. This was exactly what happened to Lin Mu – a loser who was murdered by someone he called uncle. However, things take a turn for the better when a matchless cultivator from the Cultivation Realm possesses Lin Mu's body...

I searched for `manga "killed by his uncle"` and it brought me to [this Reddit query](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/f10oaq/help_forgotten_title_of_this_reincarnation/) where someone else was looking for it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the time you put in to help find the answer FuzzyBoots!

Comment: Ah, that explains where I saw this before. I provided it as an example [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268476/manhua-about-an-alchemist-refiner-who-was-reincarnated-into-a-trash-guy/268478#268478).